# Loop of UITableViews with each UITableView have different data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to build a todo app where you can swipe through different days (UITableViews). The amount of days (UITableViews) needs to be dynamic in a variable. I want each tableview in the loop show different data from an array.

[image: Exaplanation image]

For example with this array:

```swift
var testArray = [
["Day0-0","Day0-1","Day0-2"],
["Day1-0","Day1-1","Day1-2"],
["Day2-0","Day2-1","Day2-2"]
]
```

Then I need to select my data for example like this: testArray[*indexPath of tableviews*][0]

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend using a `UIPageViewController` for starters. In a `UIPageViewController` you can have multiple child view controllers. Each child view controller can own its own `UITableView`. You can subclass a `UIPageViewController` to create each child view controller with a single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a collectionview and add tableview in collectionview cell.

CollectionCell.swift

```
class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(tableView)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["tableView":tableView]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["tableView":tableView]))
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testArray = [["Day0-0","Day0-1","Day0-2"], ["Day1-0","Day1-1","Day1-2"], ["Day2-0","Day2-1","Day2-2"]]

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[collectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[collectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))

    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionCell ?? CollectionCell()
        cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.tableView.reloadData()
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray[tableView.tag].count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = testArray[tableView.tag][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: It only works when I have an array of 3 items, when I add an 4th item to the array, it only displays right when I scroll to the bottom when the cells are outside the view

Comment: @JortBoon Did you add 4th item in testArray array?

Comment: yes I added it to the testArray array, it looks like this: var testArray = [["Day0-0","Day0-1","Day0-2"], ["Day1-0","Day1-1","Day1-2"], ["Day2-0","Day2-1","Day2-2"], ["Day3-0","Day3-1","Day3-2"]]

Comment: @JortBoon Add cell.tableView.reloadData() after cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.item Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can nest data structures in any way that makes sense to you.

If you want to have an array of table view data models, create an array of table view data models.

Typically the data model for a table view is either a simple array (for a single-sectioned table view) or an array of arrays, for a sectioned table view.

I agree with @GustafRosenblad's suggestion of using a page view controller as the interface for swiping between pages. It's a perfect for that. Each page would have a table view. You'd use the index of the current page to index into your array of data models, then fetch the data for that page's table view and display it on that page.